# Highcharts in AngularJS with inline variables (using Pablojim's Highchart-ng)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm using the Highchart charting library with AngularJS, using [Pablojim's 'Highchart-ng' module](http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/Cp73s/).

Everything is set up properly, and the following code works as intended:

```
<highchart config="{
    type    : 'line',
    series  : [{
        name    : 'Visitors', 
        data    : [1, 4, 10, 3]
    }]
}"></highchart>
```

But

```
<highchart config="{
    type    : 'line',
    series  : [{
        name    : 'Visitors', 
        data    : {{visitors}}
    }]
}"></highchart>
```

does not. (*notice the difference at 'data'*)

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'visitors' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 122 of the expression [{
    type    : 'line',
    series  : [{
        name    : 'Visitors', 
        data    : {{visitors}}
    }]
}] starting at [visitors}}
    }]
}].
```

*Note: The variable {{visitors}} is set up properly in my controller, and when using it in my template, the data works fine. It also used to work with my previous charting library, Flot.*

I've tried multiple workarounds:

- Normally I can work around this (initialization) problem by adding something like `ng-repeat="data in visitors | limitTo: 1"` to the directive, so it inits only when the variable becomes available (this works with Flot and EasyPieCharts).
- Adding `ui-refresh="visitors"` doesn't work,
- and `data: {{visitors || 0}}` doesn't work either.

**So, how can I add variables inline, within my template files?**

Comment: You are running into this problem because you're depending on someone's personal side project as a dependency. You're best off using D3 instead

Comment: I've used that before, however I kept running into problems as soon as I wanted to customize my charts. I've tried lots of libraries, and Highcharts is just really easy to use and *very very well documented*

Answer (score 0):

you can try with:

```
<highchart config="{
    type    : 'line',
    series  : [{
        name    : 'Visitors', 
        data    : visitors
    }]
}"></highchart>
```

like a var

---

OR

---

in your `ng-controller`

```
$scope.config = { 
    options: { 
        chart: { type: 'bar' } 
    }, 
    series: [{ 
        data: visitors 
    }], 
    title: { text: 'Hello' }, 
    loading: false }
```

and then in your html

```
<highchart config="config"></highchart>
```

Comment: I've tried, but that gives me both an error (*Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression ... used with directive 'highchart' is non-assignable!*) and 'No data to display'

Comment: `$scope.config = {
        options: {
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: visitors
        }],
        title: {
            text: 'Hello'
        },
        loading: false
    }`

in your html 

`<highchart config="config"></highchart>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I keep that in mind when there's no other solution, but I still highly prefer to do it inline in my template files. I don't want cluttered controllers, since I have a *lot* of pages and charts.

Comment: an object Constructor?

Comment: @JeffreyRoosendaal I comment later an example, i'm on work now :)